# Virtual Mirror kind of application in android

Tags: android, virtual, augmented-reality

I want to develop a virtual mirror kind of application similar to [this](http://www.ray-ban.com/india/science/virtual-mirror)
.As per my exploration in internet , it is based on augmented reality. I have some knowledge in augmented reality using [Qualcomm](http://www.qualcomm.com/solutions/augmented-reality) . But I discussed in Qualcomm forum and came to know that, I cant develop the Virtual Mirror application using Qualcomm. I have been exploring for other ways in internet but didn't get proper resources.
Please provide me some inputs to start and develop the application

Answer (score 0):

The AR application you are referring combines a 3D face/head tracker with a visual 3D augmentation.

The 3D face tracker provides you with the 3D pose of the detected face object (in the camera coordinate system). You can use this 3D pose (transformation) to position a virtual 3D object in overlay of the face (with OpenGL, DirectX). You can finally add the video input in the background to make an AR application wih it.

They are quite a few techniques for 3D face tracker: AAM+POSIT, Optical Flow + Tracking (KLT),  using depth information (Kinect), etc.

Some pointers to start:

[OpenCV, AAM+POSIT](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/tree/master/Chapter7_HeadPoseEstimation)

[OpenCV, Pose Estimation + Visual Augmentation](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2012/10/17/head-pose-estimation-with-opencv-opengl-revisited-w-code/)

(+ faceAPI from Seeing Machines, Face Tracking SDK from Microsoft, etc.)

A survey on the topic:
Erik Murphy-Chutorian, Mohan M. Trivedi: Head Pose Estimation in Computer Vision: A Survey. IEEE Trans. Pattern Anal. Mach. Intell. 31(4): 607-626 (2009)